# Compressing multiple files limited by size but not multipart

Tags: batch, compression, zip

It is possible to batch compress multiple files in different zip files but not a multipart zip file?

Example I have ten files of 10MB each
I want to compress them into files of 20Mb each
Let's say each file can compress to 50% then each file will be 5Mb compressed

This means that each compressed file will contain four files except the last that will include two files.

And each could be extracted separately.

Is this achievable by batch compressing? Or shall I do it manually?

Comment: There is no way to know the compression ratio in advance.

Comment: Use [SpinZip](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/spinzip-create-zip-files-with-custom-file-count-or-archive-size/)

Comment: You could probably achieve this with pure a batch script and a compression CLI tool by zipping each file to a unique ZIP file name with a unique counter, etc. like `<YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS>` and then after each one file is added to the ZIP, you then check the size of that zip and if it's `>=` greater than or equal to a certain size, then create a new unique zip and move onto the next file and repeat again. If it's not `>=` that size, add the next file and check again and so on. It'd be a task getting it setup and tested, but it may be possible... Maybe easier with PowerShell but not sure.

Comment: Spin Zip does the trick